# How to change selected text background color in Cyberfox/Firefox ver. 39.0?

Tags: firefox

I know it's not a big question but once it was possible to do it.
Now I can't find any option in about:config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I change the text highlighting selector color

This can be done with the [Stylish](http://[Stylish][1]) Firefox extension and a custom user style:

1. Install [Stylish](http://[Stylish][1])
2. Write a New Style.
3. Configure your colors.

---

#### What is Stylish?

> Restyle the web with Stylish, a user styles manager. Stylish lets you easily install themes and skins for Google, Facebook, YouTube, Orkut, and many, many other sites. You can even customize Firefox and other programs themselves.

Source [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome)

---

#### Write a New Style

- Open Add-ons

  [image]
- Select the Stylish Add-On and click `Write New Style`

  [image]
- Set name to `Firefox Selection Colors`
- Set script to:

> ```
> @namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
> @namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
>
> ::-moz-selection, 
> input::-moz-selection, 
> textarea::-moz-selection 
> { -moz-appearance: none !important;
> background: rgba(37,45,79, .6) !important;
> border-color: black !important;
> color: #ccc !important; }
> ```

- Modify the colors in the script to suit your own preferences
- Click `Save`

  [image]